# ADO to MySQL: CursorType and LockType

Tags: php, mysqli, vbscript, asp-classic, ado

I am trying to convert an `ASP-ADO` code to `PHP-MySQL` code and i have following code block to convert next:

```
Function FindBankName(bankNo)

    If IsNull(bankNo) Or IsNumeric(bankNo) = False Then Exit Function
    Dim recordSet

    Set recordSet = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Recordset")
    recordSet.Open "SELECT Id, MainPos FROM bank WHERE MainPos = "& bankNo &"", db, 1, 3
    If Not recordSet.EOF Then
        FindBankName = recordSet("Id")
    End If
    recordSet.Close
    Set recordSet = Nothing

End Function
```

Last two parameters , 1 and 3, of `Open` function is defined in Microsoft documents as:

> CursorType
>
> Optional. A CursorTypeEnum value that determines the type of cursor that the provider should use when opening the Recordset. The default value is adOpenForwardOnly.
>
> LockType
>
> Optional. A LockTypeEnum value that determines what type of locking (concurrency) the provider should use when opening the Recordset. The default value is adLockReadOnly.

Are there corresponding options in MySQLi that covers them? How should i proceed? Can i ignore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CursorType 1 is adOpenKeyset, which means all types of movement through the recordset are allowed, and you can see changes but can't see additions by other users. In other words, for a recordset where the code just gets the ID of the first record, it's a bit of overkill. LockType 3 is adLockOptimistic, which means records are locked only on update. Again, for a recordset where you're not doing any updating at all, it's more than you need.

All that said, however, we all tend to settle into cursor and lock types that work for most purposes (or, more likely, we move to other methods than `rs.Open`), and for a query that's returning two columns from one row, it really makes no difference what you use.

Bottom line is, as long as you can set your MySQL queries to allow you to do the actions you need -- reading, updating, adding, deleting --, you can safely ignore the particular parameters used by ADO.